# Is unique_lock unlocked on destruction if we already unlocked it by hand?

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

Is the `unique_lock::unlock()` function called on destruction even if I called `unlock` manually, so that unlock signal will be received on given mutex twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it will not try to unlock.  If you look at [`unlock`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.lock.unique.locking#itemdecl:5), it

> Ensures: `owns == false`.

and [the destructor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.lock.unique.cons#itemdecl:10)

> Effects: If `owns` calls `pm->unlock()`.

so since `unlock` releases the ownership, the destructor will not try to unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

No.
See the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/%7Eunique_lock):

> If `*this` has an associated mutex and has acquired ownership of it, the
>   mutex is unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

Not it is not.

Consider the `mutex` point of view, where `std::mutex::unlock` (from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock)):

> Unlocks the mutex.
>
> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution,
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Hence, it would be fatal if the lock would call `unlock` on a `mutex` that is not locked anymore.